# Number based triangle using for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop

Can you help me write a program that reads the number of rows from the user and displays the shape of a number based triangle using only for loops.

for example If R = 4 the output will be:

```
       1

     2 4 6

  3 6 9 12 15

4 8 12 16 20 24 28
```

I wrote the program, but I don't know how to make it look like a pyramid. Can someone help me with that?

And this is the program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n, i, j;

    cout << "Please enter number of rows\n";
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (j=1; j<2*i; j++)
        {   
            cout <<" ";
            cout << i*j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? What have you done so far? etc etc.

Comment: "I appreciate the help" is not a question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's obvious that I need help writing the program.

Comment: @NoorAIH: It's obvious that this is not a free program writing site. It's not a chat room, or a discussion board, or a forum. We're not going to step you through it or mentor you. This is a database of questions, and answers! Do you have a question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a question and answer website, so answer if you want or just don't. AND I DID NOT ask you to write the whole program for me, a guideline like what Ali wrote underneath is ENOUGH.

Comment: You really either use a Debugger or search the web for "c++ numbers triangle", as this assignment has been issued too many times to count.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried looking before asking this question, but I couldn't find anything that would help me with creating a pyramid and not a right triangle.

Comment: after cout<<endl; you have to put some spaces. With a little calculation you will find how much! and that would make your output like piramid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 `for` loops, you just have to understand the problem correctly then you could convert it to code easily.

from my understanding you want to have `n` rows and in `i`th row you want to have multiple of i with every number less than or equal `2*i-1` so just use one `for` to print out the new line and in every row print out that multiples.

Comment: Spoonfeeding is harmful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How could I help him without give him the answer? I didn't mean to give him answer directly but just cant figure out how to help him in this question without giving him the direct answer, if you know the better way, then it is my bad.

Comment: In this case the best way is to _not_ answer! And to teach him that he will have to do effort before posting questions in future. It might sound strange but that'll do him a _lot_ more good! It'll also stop SO from devolving into help vampire central.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit first of all thanks for your kindness to remind me that, I'm currently modifing my answer and delete this code, and just give him the direction, I'll post my new answer in moments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit please check it now.

Comment: Wow, better, nice one

Comment: I can get it to look like a pyramid. Any ideas?

Comment: @NoorAIH yes, just use spaces, one space between each number, also you have to put spaces in start of every line, that you could findout how much spaces with a simple calculation.